# What are all the entities that move in a parabola/line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are all the projectiles? Things like fireworks and potions and anything at all that have a consistent direction or is a parabola count too. This is my current list of projectiles:

- All types of Arrows (arrows, spectral arrows, tipped arrows)
- Ender Pearl
- Potion (all types)
- Eggs and Snowballs
- Trident
- Fireworks (all types)
- Fireballs (Blaze, Ghast, and Ender Dragon)
- Wither Skull (from wither attack)
- Llama Spit

Did I miss anything obvious? This doesn't seem correct...

Comment: The hook of a fishing rod?

Comment: fireworks, fireballs  and wither skulls move in a straight line, not parabola. Not sure about llama spit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly all entities can be moved in a straight line, just not very far. Dropping an object, shooting it from a dispenser, or bouncing it off a slime block will move the entity a very short distance (often less than one block) in a straight line.

Other entities that move in larger parabolas would include a fishing rod hook or TNT launched from a TNT cannon.

Most mobs can be moved by explosions, which throws them from the blast in a parabolic line outwards

Falling sand, gravel, or anvils also fall in a straight line directly downwards